# Why can I only view certain devices if I am using the 192.168.2.1 gateway

Tags: networking, routing, gateway

I have a kind of weird problem.

Every device we have at work printers, servers, etc. Exist on the 192.168.1.0 network.

We have some remote devices that are an extension of our network and they operate using a verizon private IP pool, 192.168.150.1,.2

We can only see these devices from inside our network if we manually configure our computers 192.168.2.1 gateway with a 192.168.1.*** address... The catch is this gateway technically doesn't exist on our network because no hardware serves it. So why can I change my IP on my computer to use the .2.1 gateway and I can see these devices but using my networks default gateway I cannot.

I am wondering if someone else would know the why? because that is the only way I can come up with a fix for this... And with my understanding of networking it shouldn't even work this way.

more relevant info**** Cisco 1900 series router, AT&T NVG510 serves the internet. I can draw a picture of our network if it would help as well.

Comment: I'm assuming that your main network is 192.168.1.0/24 (so a subnetmask of 255.255.255.0), and the remote network is 192.168.150.0/24 (same subnetmask as your main network). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, connected through a GRE tunnel via verizon.

Answer (score 0):

So depending on how the network administrators in your organization set up the physical network, you may have firewalls or ACLs in place to stop other machines from accessing specific subnets.

The network admins might've setup these rules to stop potential threats / attacks against servers on that subnet.

Normally, you should be able to access the other subnet IF the routers / switches were setup to route traffic properly.

So it appears there might've been something put in place to block connections between the subnets.

It would be best to ask your network administrators if they could shed some light on your predicament. Without any further information, one cannot fully say why you are experiencing these issues.

Comment: we're a small company with no network administrator. Most of this has been plug and play. Minus the Cisco configuration but that's only to handle the IPSEC/GRE stuff with Verizon.

Comment: Have you tried setting a permanent static route for the verizon addresses? If your router knows about the other network this should work, i used this approach to get to a  printer on a different network. I have to add it was in the same building, but i was on a class A segment (10.x.x.x/8) and the printer had a class B address (172.16.x.x/16) so the problem was similar on the level of ip-routing.

Comment: Yeah our cisco router uses static routes to direct the IPSEC traffic back to the network. The only reason we realized that the end points were actually working is because our printer happens to use the 192.168.2.1 gateway but actually has a 192.168.1.*** address.

Comment: Our endpoints could see the printer but couldn't really see anything else. So it's kind of a weird problem. Didn't even know that it was possible to use a gateway outside of your subnet to access the same subnet.

Comment: There are some tricks with routing tables that can make this possible, what does the routing table look like on the Cisco router?

Comment: my routing table looks like this.

S*    0.0.0.0/0 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1
      23.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        23.118.202.152/29 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1
L        23.118.202.153/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/1
      66.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 2 subnets
S        66.174.160.249 [1/0] via 23.118.202.158
S        66.174.162.132 [1/0] via 23.118.202.158
      192.168.0.0/24 is variably subnetted, 5 subnets, 3 masks
S        192.168.0.0/24 [1/0] via 192.168.1.0

Comment: C        192.168.0.0/30 is directly connected, Tunnel0
L        192.168.0.2/32 is directly connected, Tunnel0
C        192.168.0.4/30 is directly connected, Tunnel1
L        192.168.0.6/32 is directly connected, Tunnel1
      192.168.1.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        192.168.1.0/24 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
L        192.168.1.25/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0
      192.168.150.0/25 is subnetted, 1 subnets
B        192.168.150.0 [20/0] via 192.168.0.1, 2d01h

Comment: if you need an explanation of everything there I can get it. I hear it looks weird ;) Already been through this with Cisco. haha.

Comment: it does look a bit more complex than i anticipated indeed. Would you mind adding the drawing you mentioned, will save the hassle of drawing it out myself, and in this case a diagram will make more sense.